# How to update python in cmd prompt using conda?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have miniconda installed. I updated python by this command:

```
conda update python
```

But I got two versions of Python.

If I type in `python` in Anaconda Prompt, it'll enter `python 3.7.1`.

If I just open cmd to enter `python`, I'll still see old version `python 3.6.1`.

What's the problem? How to make python version the newest whenever I use python in cmd, PyCharm or anywhere else?

Comment: Please don't post code/terminal output in images. See here for why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2449192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank @Mihalis for helping me get the hang of conda environment. But your answer still doesn't fully answer my question: how to use conda environment directly in cmd, instead of opening Anaconda Prompt.

My solution is to first create an environment as @Mihalis said, and activate it. Then use `conda env list` to find out where my environment is located. Then add it to **PATH environment variables** (google it for more details). Now if I enter `python` in cmd, it'll directly call python from the conda environment, which is `python 3.7.1`.

As for PyCharm, see @Mihalis 's link there to and follow PyCharm's instructions.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that in each case "python" refers to different installations of python in your system, the one that's on windows when you type python in the cmd and the one that comes with your conda "base" environment.

You should check out how [conda environments work](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

Once you get familiar with the process it'll be pretty easy to work with your preferred version of python from wherever you need to, especially PyCharm since it comes with [built in conda support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html).

Comment: I read it. So does this mean that I can never use conda environment in cmd by just simply entering "python"? And if I uninstall python on windows, will "python" command in cmd be unavailable for me?

Comment: Oh yes you can! Just type "activate environment-name" and you'll be working with the version of python in that conda environment.

If you uninstall python it will only be available through conda environments, so yes you'd only be able to use "python" after having activated an environment.